# facebook messenger quickreplies displayed with offset

Tags: javascript, facebook, bots, messenger

I'm making a bot with facebook, everything worked fine until the quick replies started to show with an offset, meaning that I have a white space before all my quick replies...
This is quite annoying since the last quick reply is cut and is not shown properly.
This only happens on facebook browser (not in messenger) and it doesn't happen on mobile...

Has Anyone encountered this problem before?

I tried with several web browser, doesn't change anything...

[Exemple 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUoHk.jpg)
[Exemple 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bn2im.jpg)

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! As your question is currently written it is hard to see what it is exactly you want help with. Try providing code examples of what you have tried. Chances are that someone *has* encountered something like it, but since we don't know how *your* code looks, it is very difficult to give any help.

Comment: I don't think the issue is about the code since everything is fine on mobile, on messenger as well and everything worked until today. I didn't change the code, it just happened today. It seems more like a graphic issue

Comment: EDIT : Added pictures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to a bug on facebook side. They solved it by now.